Why does my PyTorch ONNX export generate an overcomplicated graph?
I am trying to export a simple neural network (NN) defined in PyTorch to ONNX format, but the generated graph seems overly complex. Here's my PyTorch model:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class LogisticNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LogisticNet, self).__init__()
        self.pol1 = nn.MaxPool3d(2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2048, 4)
        self.act1 = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, input):
        p1 = torch.flatten(self.pol1(input), 1)
        s1 = self.fc1(p1)
        output = self.act1(s1)
        return output

Here is my ONNX export code:
def export_ONNX(model):
    tensor_x = torch.rand((1, 1, 32, 16, 32), dtype=torch.float32)
    torch.onnx.export(model, (tensor_x,), "my_model.onnx", input_names=["input"], dynamo=True)

        
def main(): 
    net = LogisticNet()
    print(net)
    params = list(net.parameters())
    #print(len(params))
    #print(params[0].size())
    print(params)
    export_ONNX(net)

When I open the exported ONNX graph, I expect it to contain only the following nodes:

MaxPool
Reshape
Gemm (for the Linear layer)
Softmax

Instead, the graph looks overcomplicated with additional nodes I don't understand. Here's a screenshot of the graph:

Could anyone explain:

Why is the ONNX graph more complex than expected?
How can I generate a simplified ONNX graph that contains only the expected nodes?

Environment:

PyTorch version: 2.5.1
ONNX version: 1.17.0


To solve this and simplify the graph, I disable TorchDynamo by explicitly setting dynamo=False when exporting the model. Here's the updated export function:
def export_ONNX(model):
    tensor_x = torch.randn(1, 1, 32, 16, 32)
    torch.onnx.export(model, (tensor_x,), "my_model.onnx", input_names=["input"], dynamo=False)

From my understanding, torch.onnx.export() uses TorchDynamo, by default, to trace the model. This method results in additional nodes being introduced in the ONNX graph to handle dynamic aspects of the computation.
By setting dynamo=False, the exported ONNX graph aligns more closely with the original PyTorch operations, containing only the essential nodes such as MaxPool, Reshape, Gemm, and Softmax.

This solved the issue for me. Although, I still wonder why using Dynamo does not generate the same graph when I believe it should.
